# Auth::check() not persisting Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I'm facing a problem with laravel 5.2,

```
 public function authenticate()
    {
        $user = Auth::attempt(['email' => Input::get('email'), 'password' => Input::get('password')]);
        if (Auth::check()) {
            return redirect()->intended('default');
        } else {
            return 'wrong password or mail';
        }
    }
```

In the authenticate() function, Auth::check() is true. But then in my Autthenticate Middleware it return false...

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (!Auth::check()) { //Here Auth::check() is false
        return redirect()->guest('auth/login');
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

I can't figure what the problem is or what i am doing wrong...
I tried using Sessions but neither data doesn't persist.

Thanks

Comment: Please see if [this](http://laravel.io/forum/01-06-2015-authcheck-is-not-working) helps.

Comment: I already checked this and it didnt helped...

Comment: Are all your routes that need Auth/sessions inside the `web` middleware group?

Answer (score 2):

I did some changes in Kernel.php.

Original Code.

```
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
];
```

Modified To

```
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
];
```

---

Comment: When i'm using it, my routes donsn't work properly :/

Comment: `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,` Purpose of this is to persist the Session between request. This was your original issue and I have solved it. `\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,` Purpose of this was to show the error message that arose due to validation. If you have additional question then you should ask them in new question.

Answer (score 1):

In your middleware instead of `Auth::check()` use `Auth::guard()`

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if(Auth::guard($guard)->guest()) {
        return redirect()->guest('auth/login');
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

Please let me know if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you set your middleware to `$middleware` in Kernel.php, you should try set to `$middlewareGroups`.